# Updating an observable from a dynamically created input element

Tags: knockout.js

### [Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcaldredbann/HtnEL/4/)

---

*Here's an overview of my model structure in JSON form*

```
var json = JSON.stringify([{
    text: 'Enter your name',
    controlType: 'TextBox',
    answer: null
}, {
    text: 'Choose some of these',
    controlType: 'Label',
    answer: null
}, {
    text: 'Item one',
    controlType: 'CheckBox',
    answer: null
}, {
    text: 'Item two',
    controlType: 'CheckBox',
    answer: null
}, {
    text: 'Item three',
    controlType: 'CheckBox',
    answer: null
}, {
    text: 'Choose from multiple elements',
    controlType: 'Multiple',
    answer: null
}, ]);
```

---

I have a list of questions (detailed above), each with its respective `text` and `controlType` properties.  I've created a custom binding handler to draw the input on the form and another handler to process the `answer` based on the DOM structure of the controls created.

For example, for one particular control type I have **Multiple** as a type, which will create the following markup:

```
<select data-bind="options: ['Jan','Feb','Mar'...], optionsCaption: ' - '"></select>
<input type="text" size="5" />
```

This essentially allows a user to submit an answer for a single question as **Jan 2013** but I'm struggling to get the binding handler to work.

When I first started doing this, I extended each question with computed observables - so in this case I'd extend the `question` with the following computeds:

```
question.answer.month = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        if (this.answer()) {
            return this.answer().split(' ')[0]; // returns the month part
        }
        return null;
    },
    write: function (value) {
        if (value) {
            this.answer(value);
        }
    },
    owner: question
});
```

But I started getting into all sorts of circular reference hell - so I thought I'd take it up a level and set my `answer` observable from the DOM elements instead.

Does anyone have any ideas / tips to get this working?

**Further info**

Seems I didn't explain well enough before, so I'll try a little harder.

Each of my `question` objects has a property called `controlType`. This denotes what DOM elements should be drawn on the page.  So, for multiple (as an example) I should have the following DOM elements:

```
<div class="question">
    <label class="question-label" data-bind="text: $data.text"></label>
    <select data-bind="value: $data.answer.month, options: [month names]"></select>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.answer.year" />
</div>
```

This will let a user answer a single question - given that the question text could be something like *when were you born?* then the above DOM structure allows them to submit an answer of month and year i.e. **Jan 1990**.  Now, in the background I need to grab the values from these two DOM elements and merge them as a single answer to set the `question.answer` property.  I tried having two computed observables `question.answer.month` and `question.answer.year` but as my control types get more complicated I enter circular reference hell i.e. my answer is dependent on its counter-parts and each one the counter-parts are dependent on a parsed answer.

In short - I'm trying to set an observable's value based on an unspecified number of DOM elements, in this (the simplest) case it's a `SELECT` and an `INPUT` element.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what is not working corrently. Can you maybe describe what is wrong in your fiddle? What is happening right now what should happen instead.

Comment: @nemesv sorry for the late reply, I've got two 3 month olds that require constant attention! I've added some more info, hope it helps?

Answer (score 1):

This answer suggests an alternate solution.

First, replace the usage of the custom binding handlers by use of the [template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html). Your templates would look like this:

```html
<script type="text/html" id="Label">
    <h4 data-bind="value: answer"></h4>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="TextBox">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: answer" />
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="CheckBox">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: answer, processControl: $data" />
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="Multiple">
    <select data-bind="value: answer, options: opts, optionsCaption: '-'"></select>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: answerAddition" />
</script>
```

This is probably the main issue and the main question here. Below are some thoughts on the "multiple" question type you have, but I strongly suggest working some more on that and if you're having trouble ask an isolated question about that, as SO tends to work best if you have one question at a time.

PS. See all this at work in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3L4zB/). Notice that jQuery is hardly used anymore, which usually is a good sign (at least a sign you're using KO the way it was meant to be used).

I think you may need to work some more on the "complex" / multiple question type you have there. The above is a step in the right direction IMO, requiring also some changes in your data and view model:

- The data would contain the options, e.g.
  `opts: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar' /*etc*/]`
- The view model would contain something like
  `self.opts = ko.observableArray(data.opts || []);`
- The view model would also contain the extra observable:
  `self.answerAddition = ko.observable('');`
- As well as possibly a read only computed that returs:
  `self.answer() + ' ' + self.answerAddition()`

However, I think you'd benefit from taking this quite a few steps further, perhaps create some prototype-based inheritance and create a specialized Question constructor function to represent "month+year".

Comment: Thanks for this, my problem is that I have a lot of control types with a lot of different counter-parts, so having a specific model per control type is something I'm trying to avoid. I'm trying to keep DOM access out of my model (hence using a custom binding) but I think it'll be a lot more scalable if I can set my answer from the specific DOM elements in a given group.  The template idea is good, I could happily get rid of the `renderControl` binding in favour of templates.